# Crash on image upload

Tags: java, android, image, file-upload

Here is how I am getting an image from android camera:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] byteArrayImage = stream.toByteArray();
File f;
try
{
    f = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".png");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(byteArrayImage);
    fos.close();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I am calling this function with the file I have created:

```
public String multiPartExecute(String url, String keyOfString, String request, String keyForFile, File file)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart(keyForFile, new FileBody(file)); //here is the crash
        multipartEntity.addTextBody(keyOfString, request);
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String line = "", output = "";

        try
        {
            response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                output += line;
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) 
        {
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try
        {
            entity.consumeContent();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        return output;
    }
```

I have a crash on this line: `multipartEntity.addPart(keyForFile, new FileBody(file));`.

```
Here is the log cat output:
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773): Activity com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a70e4b40 that was originally added here
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a70e4b40 that was originally added here
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.BaseActivity.showLoadingDialog(BaseActivity.java:39)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity$CreateNewActivityTask.onPreExecute(NewEventActivity.java:470)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity.createEvent(NewEventActivity.java:423)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity$11.onClick(NewEventActivity.java:277)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I am missing? Can't find any ideas from the logcat.

**NOTE:** after commenting out the dialog show method and the problematic line, I am getting this trace in logcat:

```
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:126)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.serverlayer.BaseServer.multiPartExecute(BaseServer.java:183)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.serverlayer.AppServer.createNewEvent(AppServer.java:77)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.services.EventService.createNewEvent(EventService.java:14)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.logic.NewEventActivityLogic.createNewEvent(NewEventActivityLogic.java:16)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity$CreateNewActivityTask.doInBackground(NewEventActivity.java:476)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity$CreateNewActivityTask.doInBackground(NewEventActivity.java:1)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-05 12:14:09.591: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: check `showLoadingDialog` in `BaseActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.BaseActivity.showLoadingDialog(BaseActivity.java:39)
02-05 11:46:40.359: E/WindowManager(9773):  at com.evapp.activities.NewEventActivity$CreateNewActivityTask.onPreExecute(NewEventActivity.java:470)
```

Window leaked errors are mostly because you try to show something in a activity that doesn't exist anymore. Check this route.

**Because you use a `asyncTask` often unhandled `Exceptions` cause your activity to shutdown, opening a progress dialog of any kind will cause the above error because this activity does not exists. Make sure the dialog is dismissed or not made when this happens**

**Edit**

Now we see your real error now you commented dialog:

The class seems to be missing the Apache HttpCore library

http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: Ok, but the problem is with the file that I want to upload. Probably it is throws this exception which kills my app

Comment: Edited answer for you

Comment: So what content type should I add here?

Comment: You don't have to, you are simply missing libraries

Comment: I just mentioned it because it means `MultipartEntity` is dependent of `ContentType`

Comment: I have added `multipartEntity.addTextBody(keyOfString, request,  ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);` and it didn't crash... now working on the file upload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46834/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-tim-dinh)

Comment: changed to:
`multipartEntity.addBinaryBody(keyForFile, file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "name");
  multipartEntity.addTextBody(keyOfString, request,  ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);`